# Unit Testing - Prism - Xamarin.Forms - INavigationService issue

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms, prism

I recently started working on a Xamarin.Forms app for iOS and Android. I added a unit testing project with xUnit packages.

As of right now, The app has one view and one viewmodel. I wanted to wire everything up. so the viewmodel only has one property. the property is initialized to string.empty. So I am just checking to make sure it's not null. The viewmodel does a dependency on NagivationService.

in my App.xaml.cs - the view and viewmodel are registered for navigation.

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViewAPage, ViewAPageViewModel>();
}
```

I created a mock of the App

```
public class AppMock : App
{
    public AppMock(IPlatformInitializer initializer)
        : base(initializer) {}

    // Added as a work around
    public new INavigationService NavigationService => base.NavigationService;

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        base.RegisterTypes(containerRegistry);
        containerRegistry.Register<ILoggerFacade, XunitTestOutputLogger>();
    }
}
```

The Test Fixture

```
public class ViewAViewModelFixture : FixtureBase, IDisposable
{
    public ViewAViewModelFixture(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
        : base(testOutputHelper) {
    }

    private AppMock CreateApp()
    {
        var initializer = new XunitPlatformInitializer(_testOutputHelper);
        return new AppMock(initializer);
    }

    protected AppMock App
    {
        get
        {
            if ( app == null )
            {
                this.App = CreateApp();
            }
            return this.app;
        }
        set
        {
            this.app = value;
        }
    }
    private AppMock app;

    [Fact]
    public void Email_IsEmpty()
    {            
        ViewAViewModel vm = (ViewAViewModel)this.App.Container.Resolve(typeof(ViewAViewModel));

        string email = vm.Email;

        Assert.Equal(expected: string.Empty, actual: email);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        PageNavigationRegistry.ClearRegistrationCache();
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run the above test I am getting the following error:

```
Message: Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException : Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'App.ViewModels.ViewAViewModel', name = '(none)'.
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Prism.Navigation.INavigationService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

I am not sure what I am missing. When I run the app locally in an Android Emulator or iOS simulator it works fine. so I tried the following:

```
[Fact]
public void Email_IsEmpty()
{
    var app = this.App;
    var NavService = app.NavigationService;

    NavService.NavigateAsync("/ViewA");

    ViewA view = (ViewA)this.App.MainPage;

    Assert.IsType<ViewAViewModel>(view.BindingContext);
    ViewAViewModel vm = view.BindingContext as ViewAViewModel;

    string email = vm.Email;

    Assert.Equal(expected: string.Empty, actual: email);
}
```

this test passes, while the other one obviously fails.

Anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: Just a wild guess - `NavigationService` is registered as platform service, so it works on the emulator, but in the regular fixture, it's missing (that's what the error message says).

Comment: If we go with what you said, than the work around I mentioned in my post would not work, right?